# Simple query is taking high execution time on Oracle 19c. Any suggestions?

Tags: oracle, query-performance, oracle19c

Below are the details of view and queries. What can be done? If you guys need the exec plan and view definitions, I will post it here.

```
SQL> desc indexes_view
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 FILE_NAME                                          VARCHAR2(513)
 OBJECT_ID                                          NUMBER
 OBJECT_NAME                               NOT NULL VARCHAR2(128)
 OWNER                                     NOT NULL VARCHAR2(128)

SQL> select count(*) from containers(indexes_view);

  COUNT(*)
----------
      9310

Elapsed: 00:00:02.09

SQL> select count(*) from containers(indexes_view) WHERE file_name='/OracleHome/LargeFile.dbf';

  COUNT(*)
----------
       492

Elapsed: 00:10:22.75
```

Comment: There are ways to speed up things however: if you have an INDEX on a NOT NULL column Oracle will count the rows of the index instead of the table. In a proper relational model all tables have a primary key so the COUNT(*) will use the index of the primary key.

Comment: *"If you guys need the exec plan and view definitions"* Of course we need them. It is virtually impossible to look at a query and correctly guess why it's running slowly. Please read this post on [asking Oracle tuning questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34975420/146325). Also, it seems your using multi-tenant features so you should provide details of your set-up. Finally, is INDEXES_VIEW a view? If so, please post details (including explain plan) for the underlying query.

Comment: @SebastianSiemens - my guess is INDEXES_VIEW is a view over data dictionary views. If I'm correct then building indexes and other tuning bullets are not appropriate.

Comment: How many PDBs do you have?, and if you connect to a PDB and run the query with the WHERE clause, how long does it take?